# How to pass multiple parameters to a PreparedStatement in java?

Tags: java, prepared-statement

I am using the below code to retrive the order data from db2 and it works fine when i am passing only the BranchNumber and used the getWildcards() function since sometime i am passing multiple branch numbers .

```
public List<Order> getallorders(List<Branch> BranchNumber) throws SQLException {
        List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<Order>();        
        try {               
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append("SELECT ORDER_NUMBER as ordernumber,SERVICE_TYPE as service"
                    + "FROM ORDER WHERE "
                    + "BRANCH IN(");            
            sb.append(getWildCards(BranchNumber.size())).append(")").append(" WITH UR");
            String query = sb.toString();
            PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(query);           
            for(int i=0 ; i<BranchNumber.size() ;i++)
            {
            statement.setInt(i+1,BranchNumber.get(i).getBranch()); 
            }
            ResultSet resultSet  = statement.executeQuery();
            {
            while (resultSet .next()) {
                Order order1 = new Order();
                order1.setOrdernumber(resultSet.getInt("ordernumber")); 
                orders.add(order1);                
            }            
            }            
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return orders;
}


    private String getWildCards(int size) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i =0 ; i<size ; i++)

        {
             sb = (i == 0) ? sb.append("?") 
                     : sb.append(",").append("?");

        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Now i need to pass the startDate and endDate inside the function to retrieve the data but the preparedstatement is not formatting the select query with the passed value .

```
public List<Order> getallorders(List<Branch> BranchNumber,String startDate,String endDate) throws SQLException {
        List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<Order>();        
        try {               
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append("SELECT ORDER_NUMBER as ordernumber,SERVICE as service"
                    + "FROM ORDER WHERE "
                    + "BRANCH IN(");            
            sb.append(getWildCards(BranchNumber.size())).append(")");
            sb.append("AND ORDERDATE BETWEEN ? and ?  WITH UR");
            String query = sb.toString();
            PreparedStatement statement = 
 connection.prepareStatement(query);            
            for(int i=0 ; i<BranchNumber.size() ;i++)
            {
            statement.setInt(i+1,BranchNumber.get(i).getBranch()); 
            }
            ResultSet resultSet  = statement.executeQuery();
            {
            while (resultSet .next()) {
                Order order1 = new Order();
                order1.setOrdernumber(resultSet.getInt("ordernumber")); 
                orders.add(order1);                
            }            
            }            
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return orders;
}
```

Can someone please explain me what i am doing wrong here and how i can get the expected preparedstatement,below is the formatted query coming in my log and error message recorded,

```
SELECT ORDER_NUMBER as ordernumber,SERVICE_TYPE as service FROM .ORDER WHERE 
BRANCH_NUMBER IN(?) + AND ORDERDATE BETWEEN ? AND ? WITH UR

com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, 
SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=ORDER DATE BETWEEN ? AND;H_NUMBER IN(?) + AND;
<order_siblings_by>, DRIVER=3.63.75
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.fd.a(fd.java:679)
```

Comment: You did not set value for the question mark in preparedstatement of this line: `sb.append("AND ORDERDATE ? and ?  WITH UR");`. This may lead to all your prepraredstatement become wrong

Comment: Hi Tuyen, can you please let me know how to resolve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each `?` in the `PrepareStatement` should be assigned a value. Here is an example adopted from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) :

```
   String updateString =
        "update " + dbName + ".COFFEES " +
        "set SALES = ? where COF_NAME = ?";

   PreparedStatement updateSales = con.prepareStatement(updateString);
   updateSales.setInt(1, 500); //set value to first `?`
   updateSales.setString(2, "roasted"); //set value to second `?`
```

Comment: Thanks c0der, i have updated the code part like below and it works fine when i search the result for branch number , but its not working when i pass multiple branches 

    for(int i=0 ; i<BranchNumber.size() ;i++)
            {
            statement.setInt(i+1,BranchNumber.get(i).getBranch()); 
            }
    statement.setString (2,startDate);
           statement.setString (3,endDate);
            ResultSet resultSet  = statement.executeQuery();
            {
error:

com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-313, SQLSTATE=07001, SQLERRMC=null, DRIVER=3.63.75

Comment: updated the code like below and its now worked as expected 

for(int i=0 ; i<BranchNumber.size() ;i++)
         {
         statement.setInt(i+1,BranchNumber.get(i).getBranch()); 
         }
         statement.setString (BranchNumber.size()+1, startDate);
         statement.setString (BranchNumber.size()+2, endDate);
            ResultSet resultSet  = statement.executeQuery();
            System.out.println(statement);
            {